# I get an Assertion error when I run view_frames

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know there must be something wrong with my env but I do not know what..a lot of things started failing due to python type errors after I did a sudo apt-get upgrade

```
viki:~$ rosrun tf view_frames
Listening to /tf for 5.000000 seconds
Done Listening
python: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = tf2::TimeCacheInterface]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74635/i-get--an-assertion-error-when-i-run-view_frames/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-08-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the same happens to me. I've found in this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/53739/tf-view_frames-missing/) that now you can see the frames tree as a plugin in rqt. You have to install ros-hydro-rqt-tf-tree, assuming you are using hydro

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-03**:
Though this still fails when run as command line....I will open a bug report. Except I can not seem to find where to report a bug in view_frames?

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-09-03**:
I'm not sure if view_frames will be obsolete and rqt_tf_tree should be used instead... Maybe you can post the issue to tf repo because view_frames is part of tf and tf-tools